Make npm flatten all deps like yarn
We use npm at work for most of our projects, except for one private module where we use yarn to globally manage the versions for dependencies in other projects, simply because npm just doesn't flatten the repos "enough" (not literally like yarn classic does).
Here's an example of the node_modules from npm:
% npm list ajv
cdk@0.1.0 /home/me/git/example
└─┬ example@1.1
  └─┬ aws-cdk-lib@2.154.1
    └─┬ table@6.8.2
      └── ajv@8.16.0

Now look at yarn's structure:
% npm list ajv
cdk@0.1.0 /home/me/git/example
├─┬ example@1.1
│ └─┬ aws-cdk-lib@2.154.1
│   └─┬ table@6.8.2
│     └── ajv@8.16.0
├── ajv@8.17.1 extraneous
└─┬ table@6.8.2 extraneous
  └── ajv@8.17.1 deduped

Notice yarn happily moves all of the deps to the root level.
Without the flattened file structure, npx breaks and other child modules are only accessible when passing a full path to find them in the node_modules dir.
Things we've tried:

npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm install --prefer-dedupe
npm dedupe
npm install  --install-strategy=hoisted, nested, shallow, or linked
Adding "flat": true to package.json

We'd like to switch to using npm for consistency, but we haven't been able to get the right combinations of args with npm to get the same results as yarn classic.

I see the same nested structure in the YARN output. What exactly are you trying to flatten? The first 5 lines of both snippets are identical. Why are there two different versions of ajv in the same version of table. Maybe you shouldn't try to mimic YARN with NPM, but try to solve the problems in an NPM-like way. Can you provide a [mcve]?

If your project needs direct access to some script executable by npx, then your project should list that dependency as its own direct dependencies, and not rely on it being installed as a sub-dependency.
This is mostly by design. Relying on a specific directory structure in node_modules is, as you noticed, brittle. You have to let npm manage this.

That's kinda the question, it's not brittle if we use yarn, would it be possible to make npm do the same. I'll work on a minimal example.

@git_driver your question is 'how do i hack around how NPM is designed'. The answer is you shouldn't.
